# Criar gráfico de linha windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, chart

Ola, estou precisando criar gráficos no windows form de formas dinâmica, esta funcionando corretamente, porem eu gostaria que o gráfico fosse de linha, sendo que esta gerando de barras, alguém poderia me ajuda?
Codigo:

```
  private void FrmGrafico_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GraficoDS.LinhaRolosDataTable dt = new GraficoDS.LinhaRolosDataTable();
        LinhaRolosTableAdapter ta = new LinhaRolosTableAdapter();

        ta.Fill(dt, IDLinhaRolos);
        chartGrafico.DataBindTable(dt);
    }
```

Grafico gerado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o tipo de `chartGrafico`?

Comment: é um dos componentes do windows form, Chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só alterar o `ChartType`. Você pode ver [todos os valores possíveis na documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.seriescharttype(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
chartGrafico.Series[0].ChartType = 
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, Valeu ^^

Answer (score 0):

Este controle é feito pela *série* do gráfico, pois pode haver mais de um tipo para séries diferentes, ou seja, pode misturar gráfico de colunas com gráfico de linha.

Pode acessar essas propriedades em tempo de execução ou em tempo de design.

Em tempo de Design basta alterar o tipo do gráfico nas propriedades da série. Veja imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]